# Regex - проверка на строку длиной как минимум 1 символ

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь разобраться с регулярными выражениями. Как проверить строку, учитывая длину минимум в 1 символ (не считая пробелов с начала)? Т.е. строка может содержать абсолютно любой символ, длина у строки >=1 (но пробел(ы) в начале не учитывается).
^[a-zA-Z]{1,}$ - проверка на буквы, минимум от 1х...
Каким выражением можно заменить [a-zA-Z] для принятия любых символов, но как уже сказал не пробела в начале? Или придётся перечислить все выражения (буквы, цифры и спец.знаки) в []?Да, и пробелы внутри строки допустимы

Answer (score 1):

`\S` обозначает любой не пробельный символ (пробельными считаются сам пробел, табуляция, перевод каретки).

Если нужен именно "НЕ пробел", то можно написать так `[^ ]`

И если не задавать жесткие условия на начало и конец строки, т.е. что бы вся регулярка целиком была `\S` (без `^` и `$`) то она как раз сработает когда найдет первый же непробел.

`/\S.*/` - найдет все от первого не пробела до конца строки

Comment: спасибо, а как можно обозначить условия для начала строки? Чтобы пробелы вначале не учитывались, а учитывались только после любого непробелного символа?

Comment: @Ruben А вам их надо постичитать или что с ними сделать ?

Comment: @Ruben Я написал как. На самом деле при такой постановке вопроса отмечать начало строки не обязательно. Регулярка `\S` сработает как только найдет первый не пробел и дальше `.*` захватит все до конца строки (т.к. старается захватить как можно больше пока соблюдается условие, а `.` обозначает все кроме перевода каретки). Если конечно не оговаривать что то дополнительно

Answer (score 1):

Вот так

```
^[^\x20]
```

можно проверить чтобы в начале строки `^` символ отличался от пробела `[^\x20]` (`\x20` - это как раз код пробела, а `^` в перечислении `[]` является отрицанием).

Answer (score 1):

Может быть так:

```
^\s*\S+
```

\s - пробельный символ
\S - не пробельный символ